# What's the difference between a midlet and a corelet?

Tags: java, java-me, midlet

It's my understanding that a corelet is a Motorola-ism, but does anyone know what the difference is?  Do corelets have certain abilities that midlets don't?

Comment: I'm sure someone with a high Midi-chlorian count can answer this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a corelet is a midlet that has full read access to the phone's internal file system...

There's probably something else, but I can't remember it...  I'll see if I can find any further info

After searching around, it seems they basically add functionality to the phone, rather than run on top of it as a separate application